# drive is unavailable in zpool. How to solve?

Tags: truenas

I have just replaced the drive recently. After freeNAS 9.10 to 11.3 upgrade failed, the replaced drive become unavailable. I have already diagnosed the derive. The drive is completely healthy with no error.
Any idea?

freeNAS booting in 9.10-stable

Here are my zpool status

```
config:                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                    
        NAME                                                STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        main                                                DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                          DEGRADED     0     0     0
            gptid/1680f096-8a70-11e4-9e5e-0cc47a456f13.eli  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/16d32ae6-8a70-11e4-9e5e-0cc47a456f13.eli  ONLINE       0     0     0
            7362809097895665103                             UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/gptid/2d1c3f0a-bfff-11ea-ba5d-0cc47a456f13.eli
            gptid/177eae37-8a70-11e4-9e5e-0cc47a456f13.eli  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Comment: What is result zpool status -v ?

Comment: @mohammadmoeini it is the same result above. Thanks

Comment: did you enbale zpool for your drive , follow orcale guide :https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/819-5461/gbbvb.html